# How to add a shortcut to both the favorites and the applications screen in Ubuntu 22

Tags: dock, appmenu

I have a shortcut in the applications screen:

[image]

I want to add this shortcut to the favorites dock as well:

[image]

So, I right-click on it and click add to favorites:

[image]

But, when I do so, it removes it from the applications screen.

I want it to keep it in both areas, in the applications and in the favorites dock,

This is a GIF to represent the problem:

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

You are out of luck. Gnome Shell does no work like that anymore in versions 42 and 43.

Currently, the concept is that any application appears once, and only once, in the application overview.

- You can pin those you uses most often to the dash (what you called "the favorites dock").
- You can place some more you use frequently up and front on the first page.
- You can group some you use less commonly in folders.

They are in one, consistent place an stay where you put. So soon you will know immediately where to find that specific app.

Still, to achieve what you want, a copy of a .desktop launcher could be made so it is recognized as a different launcher and appears as a second instance. That is a hack, however, and I will not bother explaining it here. Perhaps after the explanation above, you will be able to live with how it works now.

Do not forget that hitting <kbd>Super</kbd> followed by a few letters is a far faster and more efficient way to launch an application instead of visually scanning for an icon. For those on the dash, i.e., those you use all the time, hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd> (on your text keyboard) will launch them in a split second, or switch to them when they are already open. You cannot get more productive than that.

Comment: OK :'( ⠀
⠀
⠀
⠀
⠀

Comment: If this answer resolved your question, then please consider "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the question.